# Gradle build error on run-time (Realm DB, android, kotlin)

Tags: android, gradle, realm

I am implementing an application with android studio and Realm DataBase, however i am getting a cryptic error message from `gradle` console when i run the project: My `build.gradle` file includes the following plugins:

```
plugins {
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
}
```

Exception is the following :

> 2020-11-25T15:47:14.576+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> 2020-11-25T15:47:14.576+0200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression

What can be the culprit behind this error? I do not getting other errors on the project files, or through code analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
plugins {
    id: 'com.android.application'
    id: 'kotlin-kapt'
    id: 'kotlin-android'
    id: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id: 'realm-android'
}
```

Seems like the error :

```
...TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
```

is telling you it cannot parse the list of plugins - probably because the format isn't as expected

Comment: I get the error when i put "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' in the list of plugins...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
plugins {
   id: 'com.android.application'
   id: 'kotlin-kapt'
   id: 'kotlin-android'
   id: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
   id: 'realm-android'
}
```

insted of

```
plugins{
   apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

This happens because when you using a list of plugins, the correct syntax is just putting id 'name-of-plugin'. Use the "apply plugin" only when you adding outside of the list.